# Java - thread Pool

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

My scheduled thread pool--->

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService pendingCheckScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

Thread 1--->

```
private ScheduledFuture<?> pendingTranStatusCheckHandle=pendingCheckScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new PendingTranStatusCheck(),0,checkForPendingTrans,TimeUnit.SECONDS );
```

Thread2--->

```
private ScheduledFuture<?> forcibleBatchCloseHandle=pendingCheckScheduler.schedule(new ForcibleBatchClose(), waitForPendingTrans, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

`Thread 1` is executing every 10 seconds.`Thread 2` is supposed to start after 30 minutes.

`Thread 1` is behaving as expected where as `Thread2` which is expected to start after 30 minutes,is starting after 1 hour.

Does latency in `thread1` is contributing to this problem?If so,`thread2` is supposed to be givcen priority when thread 1 finishes considering that we have only one thread in thread pool.Why `Thread2` is stretched too long to start after 1 hour?

I am clueless and expect some pointers.Please help me.

Comment: you should use code block for real code. Exclude the "Thread 1-->" stuff of make them a comment. Also a line break could help with readability.

Comment: Ok.I will follow your instructions in my next post.Somehow,I forgot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concepts are slightly off, which offsets your conclusions. You have *one thread* altogether, and two *tasks* scheduled to run on that one thread. So you can definitely expect interference if the repeated task executes for a long time, occupying the thread.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have single thread in executor.

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

It causes second Runnable wait until first Runnable finish.

Try using two threads:

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
```

Comment: Thanks..If second runnable is waiting,how long it should be waiting?Is there aany likely chance that this second runnable waiting would be expiring sometime ?

Comment: Second Runnable will not expire and will be waiting until thread become free(first Runnable finish).